# Update of VS and BottomSheet not working anymore

Tags: maui

I was using the following [BottomSheet Control](https://github.com/naweed/Maui.Controls.BottomSheet) successfully so far.

Tody, I updated my VS. Now, the BottomSheet still opens and is displayed, but when I click on any Control which is on this BottomSheet does not respond anymore and it is like I clicked "through" this View which is now on top and click into the Controls behind this BottomSheet-View-(Control).

Do you know anything like that and know what I could do to get this running again? They seem to have done a change for the Views or maybe ZIndex of Views in this Update? At least, it behaves like that.